# xcodeでrunをするときに、iOSシミュレーターが起動しません。

Tags: xcode, iphone, cocos2d-x

> **Unable to run app in Simulator**
>   An error was encountered while running (Domain = NSPOSIXErrorDomain, Code = 22)

今まで問題なかったのですが、急に上記のエラーが出てしまってiOSシミュレーターが起動しなくなってしまい、困っています。
どなたかお力を貸していただければ幸いです。

xcode6.1.1
cocos2d-x v3.2
を用いてゲームをつくっています。

Comment: Unable to run app in Simulatorで検索するといくつか対策方法が出てきますが、試しましたか？

Comment: 困ったときは再起動すればいいです。構成をいじってないのに突然！という場合は特に